# Can I aggregate Events by CustomData in Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I am trying to make a chart in Application Insights to plot the number of a certain operation performed by my API every time it is called, grouped by the language it is performed for. I have added the following telemetry event:

```
telemetryClient.TrackEvent("Count event", 
            properties:new Dictionary<string, string>(){{"language", language}}, 
            metrics:new Dictionary<string, double>(){ {"messageCount", operationCount } } );
```

In metric explorer, when I filter by my event name I can group by language as desired. I can see the operationCount value in the CustomData of the events when they are displayed as log entries, but I cannot show this value in the chart. I only get the option to aggregate on the Sum, which is a count of the number of times my API is called:

[image]

Is there any way I can make a chart with the operationCount values as the y axis and time as the x-axis, split out by language?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do it using Application Insights Analytics (and then pin to dashboard if needed).

Below is an area chart by language with 10m buckets:

```
customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| extend language = tostring(customDimensions.language)
| summarize sum(todouble(customMeasurements.messageCount)) by language, bin(timestamp, 10m)
| render areachart
```